# Angular 10 post param and body

Tags: angular, api, http-post

I am trying to hit API which accepts query parameter and body.

```
[Route("api/user/role/{notes}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IList<UserRol> roles, string notes) {
}
```

I tried following things from a number of attempts but is not working. As per posts in older Angular version below code works but i get an error saying it "expects 2-3 arguments but 4".

```
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
'Authorization': `Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
});

const bodyData = this.getBodyData(); // get whatever we want to send as body

let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('notes', 'Some notes to send');

this.httpService.post<any>(url, bodyData, headers, params);
```

When i remove the route parameter {notes} from API and try below code works:

API:
`[Route("api/user/selection/")]`

Angular:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  //params: params
};
const body = JSON.stringify({enter your role here});
return this.http.post('https://localhost:4444/api/user/selection', { notes :"test",body}, 
httpOptions);
```

How can i pass parameter with body from angular app?

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
this.httpService.post<any>(url, bodyData, headers, { params });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the {notes} argument in the RouteDefinition

```
[Route("api/user/role/{notes}")]
```

This will take note as an argument and force .NET to look for a URL like api/user/role/note. This explains why you are getting the argument error.
For you to access note as a query parameter, modify your controller to

```
[Route("api/user/role")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IList<UserRol> roles, string notes) {}
```

This will make notes an optional query param.
For the Angular part, simply do

```
this.httpService.post<any>(`${url}?notes=${notes}`, bodyData, headers);
```

You do not need this:

```
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('notes', 'Some notes to send');
```

NOTE: As good practice, consider creating a request and response interceptor. They are meant for this purposes

```
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
'Authorization': `Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
});
const bodyData = this.getBodyData();
```